# PHP Query String Variable Parameters

Tags: php

I've noticed a lot of PHP functions accept variables like this in any order.

```
<?php function_name('var8=hi, var2=hello'); ?>
```

Edit:

Like charles mentioned the string will actually look like this:

```
<?php function_name('var8=hi&var2=hello'); ?>
```

If I wanted to write a function like that, how would I do that?

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Where'd you see that code?

Comment: What you've posted is a function which accepts one argument in a form of a large string, `var8=8, var2=hello`, it's possible that the function does some parsing inside, but it's a pointless twisted way of writing functions.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't `func(array("var1" => "val1", "var2" => "val2"))`?

Comment: Yeah a lot of wordpress functions are like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just passing that function a string. For it to make any sense of that, it would have to parse the string to split up the key/value pairs.  I'm not saying it's the best approach, but if you want to do that, you should use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

Note that this is *not* by any means a language feature of PHP, but I am just providing a means to handle what you've shown.

Comment: The parameter passed is not a valid query string, ultimately `parse_str()` would not know what to do with this and likely return `$var8 = 'hi,-var2=hello'`.  But, it should be relatively simple to manipulate the current string for this function to work.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right, it's not valid, I meant for it to be valid in the question should've double checked.

Answer (score 1):

I am confused to as why you have your parameters in quotations.

When you create a function in php you are able to set default values by setting the variable, like so:

```
<?php
function foo($bar = 'pie')
{
return $bar;
}
echo foo(); // will echo pie
echo foo('bar'); //will output bar
?>
```

Comment: He has the parameters in quotations for the very same reason you have `foo('bar');`...because this is an example of invoking the function with a string parameter being passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite a common idiom, but if there is a strong use case and makes your API more usable, why not. Short of using parse_str and the URL-encoded format, you could of course write a mini parser for that.
Pretty simple would also be abusing [`parse_ini_string`](http://php.net/parse_ini_string) for that:

```
function function_name($paramstr) {
    extract(parse_ini_string(strtr($paramstr, ",", "\n")));
```

You'd probably still want default values; then also needs an `array_merge` etc.

(The reason this is not widely used is that you end up with only string scalars, and it prohibits the delimiters in the values as well. And not often are an arbitrary number of parameters really useful.)